# Kankan's android picker view

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to install this kankan's android project in my app.

http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

There is no installation guide.

**UPDATED**
After adding wheel.jar file in my project I try to run it but it gave me following runtime exception

```
12-13 18:17:13.682: E/AndroidRuntime(306): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kankan.wheel.R$drawable
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.initResourcesIfNecessary(WheelView.java:427)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.calculateLayoutWidth(WheelView.java:482)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.onMeasure(WheelView.java:518)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:619)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:280)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-13 18:17:13.712: E/AndroidRuntime(306):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you have any doubts in installation,please ask me

Comment: how to link my app to use this plugin

Comment: may i know where u download the wheel.jar?

Answer (score 4):

You can Download the code using this link. http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html.

After installation you copy the url and download entire project.

Comment: I have downloaded it successfully but how to configure my app to use it.

Comment: right click on desktop,it gives svn checkout option.click it and copy the url .

Comment: Actually your url gives two projects one is library and another is demo,it says how to use it.

Comment: I have done checkout. I got the source code now. It gives me two projects 1) Wheels 2) Wheels-Demo. Now what to do next to link it to my app?

Comment: Try to import both proj into your work space,and observe the wheels-demo ,how to use that library.If you are not aware of add library,right click on your project >properties>add library.Here you can add wheel library to your project.

Answer (score 3):

The kankan wheel project is an Android library so you can include it directly into your android project without having to copy the source and resource files.

This is how the wheel-demo project does it.  Use the wheel-demo project as a guideline to setup your project to use the wheel project as a library.

If you are using Eclipse, do the following:

1. Import the kankan wheel project into Eclipse
2. Open the properties for the Eclipse Android project you wish to use the kankan wheel library
3. Select Android from the list of properties
4. Go to the bottom of the right hand screen to the library section
5. Press Add and select wheel

You are now good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this source using SVN: http://android-wheel.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ , it will download this source code in your local machine.

Once you are done with downloading, copy and paste the necessary classes in your project, and declare all the activity classes inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I have downloaded it successfully but how to configure my app to use it.