# Android Wheel Data picker

Tags: android

I want to use android wheel to choose from some items. I just downloaded some library code from google. I am using it in my app, but it is giving some error.

```
import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelChangedListener;
import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelScrollListener;
import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.AbstractWheelTextAdapter;
import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.ArrayWheelAdapter;
```

Giving following error:

```
The import kankan.wheel.widget cannot be resolved
```

Can anyone tell me why this error is coming.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489440/kankans-android-picker-view Might help

Answer (score 0):

I have also used that library in my code and it is working fine.

possibility of error

1. You can't configure lib properly
2. In build path add lib
3. Clean eclipse.
4. Restart eclipse

   ```
   import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelChangedListener;
   import kankan.wheel.widget.OnWheelScrollListener;
   import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
   import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.NumericWheelAdapter;

   WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
   ```

Comment: hey thanks for replying. this problem is solved. but not the problem is in xml.

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: Could not resolve resource value: 0x7F020006. this is the exception coming in xml when i am using     <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/ampm"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/> can u plz tell me what is the problem here?