# How to use iOS like date picker in android application?

Tags: android, datepicker

[image]

How can i use this type of date picker in android application.

Comment: 1st thing is that every platform is having their own standard, 2nd thing is if you still want to implement the same like functionality in Android there here you go: [Android wheel-picker](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/), http://stackoverflow.com/a/8489603/379693

Comment: I would suggest you to use Android's build in date picker instead of imitating iPhone's UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for something like that, until I found [this widget](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/).

Take a look at these source code examples

[Examples](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/downloads/list)

Comment: did you find the source ?